# Running batch file to git pull from Jenkins slave

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, jenkins

I have Jenkins master and slave setup.  Both are running on Windows Server 2008.

I've setup a free-style software project and using the restrict option to force the build to run on my slave.  I'm trying to kick off a build on the slave to simply run a batch file to do a GIT PULL in our project.

Jenkins is setup as a Windows service on the slave, and it's running as the SYSTEM user.  (I've tried setting up a local user with the same result).

The build runs and simply sits there with the spinner displayed until I eventually stop the build.

I can modify the batch file to do something simple like dir > list.txt or even git status > status.txt and these fire off just fine and run successfully.

I've tried using "call" vs no call.  Nothing.  And of course the batch file runs fine if I call it directly.

Any ideas? This seems like it should be so simple.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an SSH issue with running as a System Account.

I copied keys and known hosts file to C:\Documents and Settings\Default User.ssh

And my build completed successfully.

Comment: It's good to see that you resolved your issue. Please accept your answer so that 1) Others can know that your query is resolved. 2) Others will know what the resolution was.